# How to rename multiple file extensions in ubuntu 20.04 terminal?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, batch-rename

I have hundreds of files without extension that I'd like to add a ".py" extension to all of them. As you can see manually renaming them one by one is a time consuming process. I think there might be any way of adding it all at once. Besides this I want to change extensions of many files from .mkv to .mp4.

Answer (score 2):

These are two questions in one .... for renaming files without extension to `.py`, try the following dry-run from within the directory containing the files:

```
find -type f ! -name "*.*" -exec echo {} "--->" {}.py \;
```

If you like what you see in the output, you can rename by running the following command from within the directory containing the files:

```
find -type f ! -name "*.*" -exec mv -- {} {}.py \;
```

*MKV and MP4 are two different formats and you need to convert them into each other using a media converter and renaming alone is not the right way to do it*. For renaming `.mkv` to `.mp4` anyway try the following dry-run command from within the same directory containing the files:

```
find -type f -name "*.mkv" -exec sh -c 'echo "$1" "--->" "${1%.mkv}.mp4"' _ {} \;
```

And rename when satisfied with the output by running the following command from within the same directory:

```
find -type f -name "*.mkv" -exec sh -c 'mv -- "$1" "${1%.mkv}.mp4"' _ {} \;
```

**Notice**:

You can make use of find's option [`-maxdepth`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/find.1.html) to limit how deep find will look into sub-directories under the current working directory if there are any sub-directories.